# Grading with dropdowns with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently making a system for a project. We need to create a grade calculator for the system.
I was stuck because I can only calculate the first set of data in the HTML table.

[Grade Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cG9f.png)

How can I change the other values? The data that is in the table is generated by PHP and that came from our database. I am just new to PHP, especially to ajax.

> Here is the webpage:

```
?>
    <select name="midterm" id="midterm" required class="form-control" onchange="DisableMenu()">
    <?php
        if($dblMidterm!="0.00"){
            ?>
               <option value=" <?php echo $dblMidterm; ?> " selected> <?php echo $dblMidterm; ?> </option>  
            <?php
        }
        else{
            ?>
                <option value="0.00">0.00</option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
            <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
            <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
            <option value="1.50">1.50</option>
            <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
            <option value="2.00">2.00</option>
            <option value="2.25">2.25</option>
            <option value="2.50">2.50</option>
            <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
            <option value="3.00">3.00</option>
            <option value="5.00">5.00</option>
        </select>
        <?php
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        ?>
            <select name="finals" id="finals" required class="form-control">
                <option value=" <?php echo $dblFinals; ?> "> <?php echo $dblFinals; ?> </option>                
                <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
                <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
                <option value="1.50">1.50</option>
                <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
                <option value="2.00">2.00</option>
                <option value="2.25">2.25</option>
                <option value="2.50">2.50</option>
                <option value="2.75">2.75</option>
                <option value="3.00">3.00</option>
                <option value="5.00">5.00</option>
            </select> 
            <?php
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            ?>
                <select name="overall" id="overall" disabled required class="form-control">
            <?php
                if($dblOverall!="0.00"){
                    ?>
                        <option value=" <?php echo $dblOverall; ?> "> <?php echo $dblOverall; ?> </option>
                    <?php
                }
                else{
                    ?>
                        <option value=" "></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                <?php
```

> Here is the PHP part:

```
<?php
require_once('server.php');
?>
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['dblmidterm'])&&isset($_POST['dblfinals'])){
        $dblMidterm = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['dblmidterm']);
        $dblFinals = mysqli_real_escape_string($objConn, $_POST['dblfinals']);
        $dblOverall = ($dblMidterm + $dblFinals)/2;
        $dblOverall = number_format((float)$dblOverall, 2, '.', '');
        echo '<option value="' . $dblOverall . '">' .$dblOverall. '</option>';
       $dblMidterm = 0;
       $dblFinals = 0;
    }
?>
```

> Here is the AJAX part:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#midterm, #finals").change(function() {
        var midterm = $("#midterm").val();
        var finals = $("#finals").val();
        if(midterm != "" && finals!= "") {
            $.ajax({
                url:"compute.php",
                data:{dblmidterm:midterm,dblfinals:finals},
                type:'POST',
                success:function(response) {
                    var resp = $.trim(response);
                    console.log(midterm);
                    console.log(finals);
                    console.log(resp);
                    $("#overall").html(resp);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#overall").html("<option value=''> </option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't select specific selects, so JavaSript finds the first one.
You need to do some reading on `this` keyword.

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr'); //finds the row the select you used is in
var midterm = row.find('#midterm').val(); //finds the #midterm in that row
var finals = row.find('#finals').val(); //finds the #finals that row
```

Comment: Hello there, I am able to change the values now of the rows but then the result is always on the first row too, what should I do to correct?

Comment: same way: row.find("#overall").html("<option value=''> </option>"); and row.find("#overall").html(resp);